# How to hide one part of html code from base.html in django?

Tags: html, django

I have base.html that loads basically whole site. Inside that base.html I want to hide on home page, but not on others. How to do this?

Tried to do like this, but something messed up...

This is base.html (This is a part I want to hide in home.html)

```
{% block header_parent %}
<!-- ***** Breadcumb Area Start ***** -->
<div class="mosh-breadcumb-area" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/core-img/breadcumb.png' %})">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="bradcumbContent">
                    <h2>{{page_title}}</h2>
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{page_title}}</li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<!-- ***** Breadcumb Area End ***** -->
{% endblock %}
```

Page with header

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

{% block header %}{% endblock %}

<p>Every other page.</p>


{% endblock content %}
```

This is home.html (I don't want to be show part of header here)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<p>Home</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To hide a portion of a template to extend :**

You just have to explicitly call the block tag with nothing inside it.
**In your home.html :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block header_parent %}
<!-- Nothing here (to override this portion defined in the parent template) -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: But nothing in base.html? Just in home.html

Comment: The block is keep unchanged in `base.html` but **override** it in `home.html` like show above